# signature error

Tags: string, encoding, utf-8, apex-code, amazon-sns

This shows error "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS.

```
     string url;
    integer statuscode;
    String date1=json.serialize(Datetime.now());
    if(date1.contains('"')){
    date1=date1.replace('"','');}
    String algorithmName = 'HmacSHA256';
    date1=date1.substring(0,(date1.length()-5));
     date1=date1+'Z';
     date1=EncodingUtil.UrlEncode(date1,'UTF-8');    
     String Action=EncodingUtil.UrlEncode('CreateTopic','UTF-8');
     String AccessKey=EncodingUtil.UrlEncode('APIKEY','UTF-8'); // API key hide due to security resion but i check it work fine for SES
     String Signaturemethod=EncodingUtil.UrlEncode('HmacSHA256','UTF-8');
     string str= 'GET\nsns.us-east-1.amazonaws.com\n/\nAction='+Action+'&Name=Testtopics&AWSAccessKeyId='+AccessKey+'&Timestamp='+date1+'&SignatureVersion=2&SignatureMethod='+Signaturemethod; 
    Blob mac = Crypto.generateMac(algorithmName,Blob.valueOf(str),Blob.valueOf('SECURITYKEY')); //blob value of key used in signature
    url='https://sns.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/?Action=CreateTopic&Name=Testtopics&AWSAccessKeyId=ACCESSKEY&Timestamp='+date1+'&SignatureVersion=2&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&Signature='+EncodingUtil.UrlEncode(EncodingUtil.base64Encode(mac),'UTF-8'); // final url
```

Comment: provide the link for previous question please.

Comment: What language is this? I certainly don't see any HTML. Please tag accordingly.

Comment: are you sure about the version in last line `&SignatureVersion=2`

Comment: @Tauseef yes its SignatureVersion=2 please help if u know the solution for this

Comment: @JonathonReinhart This is the code for APEX Langauge please help if u know the solution for this

Comment: @Aisha try apppending an empty string at the end, that is `+EncodingUtil.UrlEncode(EncodingUtil.base64Encode(mac),'UTF-8')+'';`

Comment: @Tauseef I tried it but still get the same error

Comment: @Aisha AWS must have some interface on web to test your security key. it may be possible that your development key or the actual production key is not valid.

Comment: @Tauseef I checked it and it's status is active and also it work fine for SES API of AMAZON.I do the testing for SES just before SNS with same keys.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much Idea about the AWS but below is what I was able to find. can't test these things anywhere to figue out the problem.

> A common cause of the error message below is not properly creating the string to sign, such as forgetting to URL encode characters such as the colon (:) and the forward slash (/) in Amazon S3 bucket names.

```
<Error>
    <Type>Sender</Type>
    <Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
    <Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. 
    Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. 
    Consult the service documentation for details.</Message>
</Error>
```

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-2.html

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/BucketRestrictions.html

Comment: Thanks for reply.I tried a lot and also encode date and signature value but still find the same error.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might be missing a trailing single quote at the end of your url. See if that makes a difference.

```
url="https://sns.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/?Action=CreateTopic&Name=Testtopics&AWSAccessKeyId=ACCESSKEY&Timestamp='+date1+'&SignatureVersion=2&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&Signature='+EncodingUtil.UrlEncode(EncodingUtil.base64Encode(mac),'UTF-8')+"'";
```

Comment: i tried it by adding an empty string at the end but i still get the same error